# Lifetime of, and repairing, an aluminium AC condenser?

Tags: hvac

I have an LG 1.5 ton AC. It stopped cooling. The Service eng. checked it and identified a coolant leak at the joint of the aluminum condenser and the copper tubing.

He explained that welding it is not possible between the aluminum condenser and the copper tubing. He wants me to replace it with a copper condenser.

I just want to confirm if it is correct that you cannot weld this leak?

What is the expected life of an aluminum condenser in an AC?

Comment: Does *anyone* know of a sealant could seal a small leak at such a joint? How long has the unit been in service? It could be that the entire condensing unit should be replaced with a new one.

Comment: There are epoxy's that can seal leaks but they really don't hold up in my experience and then you are out the service call and the Freon added to the unit when it fails if the tech will even try it. The system would need to be pulled to a vacuum and recharged after the epoxy cures. I Tryed this at my plant and it only held for a couple of weeks. If I was working on someone else's unit I would not take the chance because when it fails you won't be happy throwing the service call and recharg $ down the drain.

Answer (score 1):

Welding of aluminium to copper is frequently done by pressure welding. During that process both materials are pressed together under very high pressure thereby creating a durable bond. Such welding can not be done by a service engineer. So for him the only option is to select two materials of the same kind. Copper tubing and also copper condenser and braze the two together.

Therefore the technician is right.

As far as the expected life of the aluminium condenser is concerned. If the environment is more or less neutral, a long life can be expected. In your case you were just unlucky the joint failed.